# After deployment to AWS I get 502 bad gateway error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I successfully deployed the nodejs application to aws elastic beanstalk using gitlab ci/cd. However, when I try to visit the link of the aws environment I get 502 bad gateway error. I downloaded the logs file and below are last logs that I get.

```
2022/03/20 04:58:57 [error] 723#723: *97 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.0.96, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.13.104"
2022/03/20 04:59:02 [error] 723#723: *99 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.73.189, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.13.104"
2022/03/20 04:59:12 [error] 723#723: *101 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.0.96, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.13.104"
2022/03/20 04:59:17 [error] 723#723: *103 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.73.189, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.13.104"
2022/03/20 04:59:27 [error] 723#723: *105 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.0.96, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.13.104"
2022/03/20 04:59:32 [error] 723#723: *107 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.73.189, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.13.104"
2022/03/20 04:59:42 [error] 723#723: *109 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.0.96, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "172.31.13.104"
```

What is going wrong in this case and how to solve it?

**UPDATE**

Here is the ED platform I am using

```
Node.js 16 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
```

I am using HTTP for now.

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear. You haven't provided any details of your EB setup, not even a EB platform version that you are using.

Comment: @Marcin What is EB details you want?

Comment: Your EB platform version would be a good start. What about any .ebextentions, Dockerfile? How exactly do you test your app?  Does it work without using gitlab ci/cd? Do you use HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @Marcin I updated the question and I don't have any `.ebextensions` or Dockerfile. It just simply deploys via CI/CD successfully. I am using postman and make a GET request to the URL mentioned in All Envrionments in EB console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Node.js` uses port 3000 by default, but EB [uses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html#nodejs-platform-proxy.alami) `8080`:

> By default, Elastic Beanstalk configures the proxy to forward requests to your application on port 8080.

Your error indicates that your application does not use port 8080, which would explain why EB fails to connect.

Comment: how do I fix it, as I am using a different port that I have configured in my service  as 8091 port, Kindly explain..

Comment: I have tried this solution but it is not working at all!

Comment: @AhsanKhan So why not make question specific to your issue and setup?